# Customize error message in yii2 REST API

Tags: api, rest, error-handling, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to customize this following error message

```
Error 404: Not Found
{
    "name": "Not Found",
    "message": "Object not found: 6",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 404,
    "type": "yii\\web\\NotFoundHttpException"
}
```

to:

```
Error 404: Not Found
{
    "name": "Not Found",
    "message": "Country not found for: 6",
    "code": 404,
    "status": Error
}
```

Where is need to write this customization code?

Comment: throw your own exceptions maybe and write w.e. in message

Comment: exactly, something like this... throw new NotFoundHttpException("Country not found for: ". $country_id);

Comment: But im using basic rest calls ..Idont have any functions,my controller is ` class CountryController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Country'; }`

Comment: http://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest-error-handling/
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-error-handling.html

Answer (score 2):

try this (e.g. config/web.php):

```php
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        // ...
        'response' => [
            // ...
            'on beforeSend' => function (yii\base\Event $event) {
                $response = $event->sender;
                if (404 === $response->statusCode && is_array($response->data)) {
                    $response->data['code'] = $response->data['status'];
                    $response->data['status'] = 'Error';
                    unset($response->data['type']);
                }
            },
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override errorHandler which extends yii\web\ErrorHandler, just convertExceptionToArray method

```
/**
 * Converts an exception into an array.
 * @param \Exception|\Error $exception the exception being converted
 * @return array the array representation of the exception.
 */
protected function convertExceptionToArray($exception)
{
    if (!YII_DEBUG && !$exception instanceof UserException && !$exception instanceof HttpException) {
        $exception = new HttpException(500, Yii::t('yii', 'An internal server error occurred.'));
    }

    $array = [
        'name' => ($exception instanceof Exception || $exception instanceof ErrorException) ? $exception->getName() : 'Exception',
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        'code' => $exception->getCode(),
    ];
    if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
        $array['status'] = $exception->statusCode;
    }
    if (YII_DEBUG) {
        $array['type'] = get_class($exception);
        if (!$exception instanceof UserException) {
            $array['file'] = $exception->getFile();
            $array['line'] = $exception->getLine();
            $array['stack-trace'] = explode("\n", $exception->getTraceAsString());
            if ($exception instanceof \yii\db\Exception) {
                $array['error-info'] = $exception->errorInfo;
            }
        }
    }
    if (($prev = $exception->getPrevious()) !== null) {
        $array['previous'] = $this->convertExceptionToArray($prev);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

The code above is from Yii, you just need to tweak it a little.
Then add it to config : ( usually web.php)

```
    'errorHandler' => [
        'class' => 'your\namespace\YourErrHandler',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what I do is right or wrong but it works.
Just create a new custom php file called ErrorMsg.php

```
<?php
use Yii;
use yii\web\HttpException;
class ErrorMsg extends \Exception
{
    
    public static function customErrorMsg($error_code,$message = null, $code = 0, \Exception $previous = null,$extra_content=NULL)
    {
        $httpException = new HttpException($error_code,$message,$code,$previous);
        Yii::$app->response->statusCode = $error_code;
        $custom_err = array(
                            'name'=> $httpException->getName(),
                            'message' => $message,
                            'code' => $code,
                            'extraContent' => $content,
                            'status' => $error_code
        );
        return $custom_err;
    }
```

and call the functions wherever you want. Example

```
return ErrorMsg::customErrorMsg(400,"Message Here",11,NULL,"Extra Content Here");
```